# Something wrong with the navbar style

Tags: css, materialize

I just created a Materialize CSS navbar and I placed some icons to the text.

I tried to change the priority of the code but no luck.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
   <nav>
     <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-4">
       <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><img src="logo.png" width="315" height="70"></a>
       <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="small material-icons">home</i>Homepage</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="small material-icons">store</i>Marketplace</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

The main problem is that the text is floating off the nav bar:

https://i.gyazo.com/2130fead13cc9e03e8133b8a7466e9b2.png

Comment: Must see (S)CSS on elements, please post that and helping you will be possible i think :)

Comment: Nevermind I forgot that I cant use small before the icon

Comment: Ah ok :) still i found a way for you, hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is pushing out the content i see.

```
nav > div.nav-wrapper > div > ul > li > a {
    display: flex;
}
```

This is a dirty fix hope it helps, maybe theres better css for it but this works, you can also add some margin to the icon maybe.

```
nav > div.nav-wrapper > div > ul > li > a > i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```